# Checking Users in a Queue: Algorithm for managing Priority?

Tags: algorithm, queueing, real-time

Let's say I have a large set of users in a queue that I query each user against a **rate-limited** API periodically.  Once all users have been queried, the process is restarted.  The rate limit is applied such that I cannot check all users within a *reasonable* amount of time (> 1 day to check everyone).

Every time I check a user, I am able to check when they were last active.  If a user has been actively recently (let's say last few days), then they should have priority over users that have not been active at all (> a year).  However, the probability of an inactive user being queried should still be more than 0.  Are there any existing research/methods on how to manage this queue efficiently?

Currently what i'm thinking is doing a simple priority queue and have user's initial value be the time they were last active.  Any time a user is queried, their position in the queue is replaced with the date they are last active + some random number generated from a distribution so that all users can be checked eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought I decided to use a bayesian model to infer each user's time between events.  I assume that each user's amount of activity within a time-period follows a poisson distribution.  It follows that the time between each event follows an exponential distribution.  For the rate parameter, i assumed it to be gamma distributed.  Therefore, the posterior distribution is a lomax distribution.  For every user I add to the queue, I sampled from the posterior as their new priority #.  When a user has a recent activity, i update their user-specific hyperparameters and then resample a new priority value.  This allows me the flexibility to adjust each user's priority based on data as well as set priors for new users that i dont have any information on.